# jQuery animate() not working with colors

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do some simple jQuery test in Confluence 4.1.9.

```
$("div#test").css("background","#F00");
```

works, but

```
$("div#test").animate({background:"#F00"});
```

doesn't. Am I missing something? Or maybe animate() just doesn't work in Confluence? Hopefully someone can help me out with this. Thank you.

**[Update]**

Thank you guys, it totally worked!
But fyi, it did not work in preview, which made me scratch my head a bit. Good thing I decided to save the page and see what happens anyway. :P

Comment: If you want to animate the colors, you should load jQuery ui too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jQuery Core does not support color animations out of the box.

You will have to use something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) or a standalone [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) for your call to `animate()` to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Animation doesn't work with color

Hovewer if you want to avoid JQuery UI you can use **transitions**:

```
$("div#test").css( { "background": "#F00",
                     "transition": "color 0.4s" } );
```