# Animate background-color on mouseenter event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have it so that when the mouse enters the `.container` elements the `background-color` of `#facial` element slowly transitions to white from blue.

I've read that you have to use jQuery's `.animate()` function to achieve this.

It doesn't seem to work. I've read on the forums you need something called JQuery UI, but those posts were older. I also do not see this option within my JsFiddle. Anybody know why this script is not working?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.container').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#facial').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffffff'},'slow');
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/b008nczk/30/)

Comment: `background-color` is NOT animatable property (see list of animatable properties here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp). You do need either jQuery UI library or a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461984/jquery-animate-not-working-with-colors ... Or you can try CSS transitions.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm going to just use a CSS transition instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `css` `:hover` ,  existing `transition` property set to `8.5s`

```css
#test_box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  transition: background 2s ease;
}
#test_box:hover {
  background: green;
}
body {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.container {
  margin: 200px auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 478px;
  height: 200px;
}
#facial {
  float: right;
  width: 239px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #008aaf;
  transition: background 8.5s ease;
}
#facial h1,
#facial h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container:hover > #facial {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/enn2yyh7v/Facial.jpg" />
  <div id="facial">
    <h1>Facial</h1>
    <h2>Marketing Material</h2> 
  </div>

  <div id="test_box">...</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b008nczk/32/

Comment: Thank You. That does make sense. So i should probably just do any background-color transition in my CSS, and avoid it altogether within Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Color animations need jQuery UI which extends the animate method.

https://jqueryui.com/animate/

In fact to animate the background-color with jquery you need the Color plugin.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b008nczk/34/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //1.1 On hover the background of #facial will turn white
    $('.container').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#facial').animate({
            'background-color': '#ffffff'
        }, 1000);


    });
});
```

Also as a heads up when you include jQuery in jsfiddle it automatically includes jqueryui as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Seems to still be working when i click your JsFiddle link. Also if this is true shouldn't it be working in my JsFiddle?

Comment: @StinkyTofu in my fiddle if you look at external resources I added the jquery color plugin. Jqueryui extends the animate function to work with colors. The color plugin extends the jquery ui animate extension to work with background color.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using CSS. The project started as an actual Jquery project, but ended up being completed with pure CSS. Thanks guys! Here are the results.

```
.container:hover > #facial {
  background: #fff;
}
```

[Results!](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/b008nczk/69/embedded/result/)