# jquery animate css style not working

Tags: jquery, css

I created this code for an animated table -> http://codepen.io/CliffTam/pen/qRGQjE

When you click on an item, the item will expand.

My problem is with styling the item when I click on it.  I can change the font size and padding but I cannot change the font color or line height.

This is my code to trigger the animation:

```
   $el.animate({
            "font-size": "26px",
            paddingTop: 15,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 15,
            paddingLeft: 10            }).next().slideDown();
```

If I try this, change the color to red, it doesn't work:

```
   $el.animate({
            "font-size": "26px",
            "color": "red",
            paddingTop: 15,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 15,
            paddingLeft: 10            }).next().slideDown();
```

Can someone explain to me why the code doesn't worK?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know .animate() affects on numeric attributes only, like width, height, margin, padding etc., but not colors or similar.. To change the color you need to set class i.e. `.red { color: red;}`, append `transition: color .5s` to `el` selector and use jquery methods like `.addClass, removeClass, toggleClass`

Comment: This post also seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461984/jquery-animate-not-working-with-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Core library **does not support color animations** by default.

You will need to use [jQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/) for properties like `color` or `background-color` to work within the JQuery functions like `animate()`.

**One of the Solutions:**

If you can, just include the JQuery UI library after the JQuery. Many versions of the same can be found [here](http://code.jquery.com/ui/)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

[I have updated your Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/GraPmB)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the effect you are trying to achieve, you can achieve it by adding:

```
$('dt').css({"color" : "black"});
$el.css({"color" : "red"});
```

beneath your `$el.animate({ [...] }).next().slideDown();` statement.

To enable the color transition to animate, you can then add:

```
dt {transition: color 0.4s linear;}
```

to your css styles.